# Passing NOW() function as non string when using PDO-MYSQL prepared statements for multiple inserts?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am inserting multiple rows in a single query in my table with 7 columns(Showing here only 3 columns to make it easy to read and type). One of the column called created_on is the current time of insert. However I am building the array upfront and passing now() as a string while building my array. However while doing this I get an Out of range value for column 'created_on' because MySQL is receiving the function now() as a string 'now()' from PHP  instead of now(). How can I pass now() correctly to MySQL so that the query runs correctly. If I remove the quotes while creating the array then I get a PHP error. I am preparing my query in the following manner:

```
    $datafields = array('fielda', 'fieldb', 'created_on');

    $data = array(value1a, value1b, 'now()',value2a, value2b, 'now()' ....valueNa, valueNb, 'now()');
```

where N(and variable $N) is total number of rows and is typically around 100,000 to a million for every insert in a table

```
    function placeholders($text, $count=0, $separator=","){
        $result = array();
        if($count > 0){
            for($x=0; $x<$count; $x++){
                $result[] = $text;
            }
        }

        return implode($separator, $result);
    }
    $pdo->beginTransaction(); // also helps speed up your inserts.
    for($i=0;$i<$N;$i++){
        $question_marks[] = '('  . placeholders('?', 7) . ')';

    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO code (" . implode(",", $datafields ) . ") VALUES " . implode(',', $question_marks);
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    try {
        $stmt->execute($data);
    } catch (PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
    $pdo->commit();
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of now(), use date('Y-m-d H:i:s')

Edit
I'm assuming the created_on is of type datetime

Comment: this would give me the time when the array is created not when the data is inserted in the table.  I can live with this but I wanted to know if there was a way to save the exact time of data insert into the table